Why is the "decision" version of the local Hamiltonian problem promised to have a positive gap?
The Wikipedia article on the local Hamiltonian problem is ungrammatical and unclearly written. I think that this is what it is supposed to say:

The decision version of the $k$-local Hamiltonian problem is a type of promise problem and is defined as: Given a $k$-local Hamiltonian $H$ on $n$ qubits, two real numbers $\alpha > \beta$, and a promise that the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $H$ satisfies either (a) $\lambda \geq \alpha$ or (b) $\lambda \leq \beta$, determine which of these two cases holds.

Assuming that I got that definition correct: why are we allowed to assume this promise? If you were to give me some explicit $k$-local Hamiltonian on $n$ qubits and asked me to find the ground-state energy, and I wanted to map that question to a corresponding decision problem, then how would I choose the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? If I didn't already know the ground-state energy, then how could I know that it didn't happen to lie in between whichever values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that I guessed? What determines the size of the energy gap $\alpha - \beta$ in the corresponding promise problem?
Note: I'm not asking why the promise is important. I certainly understand why the promise qualitatively changes the nature of the problem away from a hypothetical non-promise decision problem "Given $H$ and a real number $E_0$, is $\lambda \leq E_0$?". Instead, I'm asking why the stated "promise" version of the problem is the "better" analogy to the original, non-decision problem (whose output is a real number and therefore does not fall within the standard formulation of a computer-science "problem", i.e. a language on a finite alphabet). Therefore, I think this is more of a physics question than a computer science question, which is why I'm asking it here and not on CS SE.

I think I figured it out.
The issue is that you can only use a finite number $m$ of bits to specify your problem instance. Therefore, you can only specify $H$ and $E_0$ to some finite precision $\delta$, which in turn determines some uncertainty $\epsilon$ in the ground state energy. There's no need for your algorithm to be able to compute $\lambda$ to within greater precision than that $\epsilon$.
(More precisely, the uncertainty in $H$ determines some uncertainty $\epsilon_\lambda$ in the GS energy $\lambda$ of $H$, and there's another uncertainty $\epsilon_{E_0}$ in the ansatz $E_0$ that you are comparing $\lambda$ to. There's no need to to compute the approximate value of $\lambda$ if that approximate value lies within the interval $E_0 \pm (\epsilon_{E_0} + \epsilon_\lambda)$ - because in that case, the ranges of uncertainty overlap, so the nominal inequality between $\lambda$ and $E_0$ no longer necessarily holds and so becomes meaningless. If the GS energy $\lambda$ happens to lie within that uncertainty range, then it doesn't matter what your algorithm outputs, because you're exceeding the precision of the problem inputs anyway.)
I think that in general, if the answer to a computational problem depends continuously on continuous parameters in the problem instances, then the "decision version" of that problem will usually be a promise problem rather than a decision problem.
